# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443 without the use of SSL/TCP

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ssl

I am making an app with the `express.js` framework for `node.js` but I keep getting the error.

```
(node:3688) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3688) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3688) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

It seems like this error is caused because of an incorrect use of SSL/TCP but the problem is that I do not use it anywhere. I start the app on port `80` without any information provided that may be regarded as `ssl` by the app (like certificate or secret key). Looks like the problem is not even connected to me requesting the web page in the browser; I am not sure, however.

If I start the app on a remote server with ip (2****1) on port 4317 and type `http://2****1:4317` in the browser (try to use the website), it sometimes gives a similar error to the console: `Error: unable to verify the first certificate` altohugh I do not use `https` and anything related to `ssl`. What can be the reason for that and how to fix it?

To be more specific, some code of how I handle the app.

```
let express = require('express');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let app = express();
app.use('/static', express.static(`${__dirname}/static`));
app.set('views', `${__dirname}/views`);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
let urlEncodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});
var oauthChecker = async function(req, res, next)
{
...
};
global.app.use(oauthChecker);
global.app.get('/sth', async (req, res) =>
{
...
}
global.app.post('/sth', async (req, res) =>
{
...
}
//some similar `get` and `post` handlers.

global.app.listen(global.config.website.port);
```

and the way I send those `post` requests from the client is with the use of JQUERY

```
$.post('/sth', {"data": JSON.stringify(res)}, function (q)
{
    location.replace(`${q}`);
});
```

Comment: The crux is likely in the specific implementations - which are not shown.  See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and focus on both **reproducible** and **minimal**.

Comment: I understand that there is something specific causing the problem but I do not understand where to find it. Node does not give a line in my code that causes the problem. At first, I want to understand where tо look for a mistake.

Comment: All I could say is from looking at what you showed so far that it is not in the code you've showed so far. I have no idea of the rest of your code so I cannot give you any more detailed hints. A common thing to deal with such problems is to simplify your code more and more until the problem vanishes. Then look at the last change which made the problem vanish.